# Summation $1-4x+9x^2-16x^3 + \cdots ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Taylor series gives $$\frac 1 {(1+x)^2}=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+\cdots$$

is there a nice expression for $1-4x+9x^2-16x^3 + \cdots ?$

It would be helpful for a problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate, but it's not an _exact_ duplicate: the original question has $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^n$, whereas this question asks for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2(-x)^n$.

Comment: @r9m Signs alternate in this question, but substituting $-x$ for $x$ in the link does the trick. The question isn't quite the same, though, and an extra step is required.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys, im fine now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way - I'll leave you to do the detailed calculations.

Start with $f(x)=-1+x-x^2+x^3-\dots=-\cfrac 1{1+x}$

Then $f'(x)=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+\dots$

And $xf'(x)=x-2x^2+3x^3-4x^4+\dots$

So that $\left(xf'(x)\right)'=1-4x+9x^2+-\dots$

---

I hope the method proves helpful

Answer (score 6):

For $|x| < 1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)^2 (-x)^n 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(x\frac{d}{dx} + 1 \right)^2 (-x)^n
= \left(x\frac{d}{dx} + 1 \right)^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n\\
&= \left(x\frac{d}{dx} + 1 \right)^2 \frac{1}{1+x}
 = \frac{d}{dx}\left[ x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\right]
 = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\right]\\
&= \frac{1-x}{(1+x)^3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: To live in your mind. What a route to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n(n+1)^2x^n
$$
should be exactly what you need, if I understand your question.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Then enlighten me: What kind of an expression are you after?

Comment: @LTS Well what Arthur wrote down there is a really nice expression for what you wrote down on your question. If you were looking for something specific you should have said it in your question.

Comment: He wants to express the Taylor series in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $$1-4x+9x^2-16x^3 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (n+1)^2 x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (n^2+2n+1) x^n$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @LTS: rudeness/arrogance is not welcome here. Many people could mock you for not being able to solve the easy question, if they wanted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The people posting trivial answers couldn't, else they would actually solve it.

Comment: @LTS Perhaps you are unable to understand the meaning of the word "HINT".

Comment: @lts: I preferred to withdraw my answer.

Comment: @LTS And as far as solving the series is considered, if that was your question, then nobody would have even cared to do so for it is already a  near duplicate. And please.. learn some decency and modesty... this is a public site, if you cannot respect others, I don't think anyone will answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply your expression by $(1+x)^3$ and find out.